# 「表{おもて}」、「表面」、「外観」の違い

Tags: word-choice

「表{おもて}」、「外観」、「表面」
三つの言葉の違いは何ですか。

Comment: ご自分で調べてみられて、今のところどんな類似点や相違点を見つけられましたか。

Answer (score 3):

表 is the front, as opposed to 裏, the back.

外観 is the outside appearance, as opposed to 内観, the internal appearance.

表面 is usually translated as "surface".

Comment: でも・・「[表]{おもて}」って、文脈によって、「表面」って意味でも使われることもありますし、「外観」って意味で使われることもありますよね・・・使い分けを教えないで、辞書の定義だけ貼って済むなら、サイトで質問する必要ないでしょ？